# Swap memory 95% on SQL server running on Windows Server

Tags: windows, sql-server, virtual-memory

I had an interesting situation the other day where a customer's SQL server was at 95% swap memory utilisation. This occurred on a Windows server running SQL Server.

The customer has 64GB RAM, and the swap is being managed by Windows.

The following article suggests:

```
When the max memory setting is changed, SQL Server discards everything in the buffer and starts over.
```

I am curious to know if anyone has tried this before?

The issue was in a production environment, so we couldn't experiment at the time. And I am not sure how to force the 95% swap utilisation within our test environment Today I thought I would canvas ServerFault to see if anyone had done something like this before while swap memory was at 95%.

Comment: Were their processes other than SQL server using a lot of RAM? SQL should consume nearly all the available RAM and yield it back when other processes need it. However, I always set the maximum memory to less than the physical RAM to leave enough for other processes. I’m not sure why the page file would be consumed because you don’t  mention what was actually using the memory. You can modify the max memory whenever. SQL just starts flushing out in memory data pages to free up the RAM.

Comment: @Appleoddity - Have the SQL max memory set to 53.5GB. In task manager the SQL process was exactly that. If the other processes on the server required more RAM, and I were to adjust down the amount of RAM allocated to SQL would that still send up the swap utilisation? (for a moment, ignore the obvious option of just increasing the overall RAM on the VM).

Comment: Only if you offset all of that RAM by taking it away from the SQL server’s max memory. I think you’re looking in the wrong place. This is not an SQL server problem. The point is that leaving a few GB for the OS and other processes on an SQL server should be enough. If you’re using that much pagefile then what is using the page file? You need to check in resource monitor or with process explorer. Apparently something is using a lot of extra RAM. But reading your post again you suggest it is SQL using the swap space. Are you sure? How?

Comment: I just watched a heavily used SQL server restart. Server has 96GB RAM and a 16GB page file. Max memory for sql is set to 80GB. Large jobs started requiring all available memory. I watched SQL start consuming memory up to 80GB. Windows paged out a couple other processes but SQL “throttled” itself to 80GB while using less than 1GB in the pagefile. 11GB RAM remained free on the server and it hummed along.